# Replacing a non-failing drive in a RAID-0 array

Tags: raid, rebuild, raid-0

I have a Windows 7 machine booting on a RAID-0 pair of 500GB disks, controlled by an ICH9R. One of those was indicating an end-To-end SMART failure, so I added a spare disk as a temporary workaround, before receiving another to replace the failing one. The RAID-0 rebuilt on the spare and dropped the failing one from the array, as expected.

Now that I received the new drive, **what are my options to reintegrate it in the array?**

My first thought was to simply clone the temporary disk to the new one while the array is offline, but **shouldn't there be a way to force a second rebuild**, just as if the temporary drive had a warning, and drop that temporary from the array?

Comment: The machine is a gaming platform, so there's no critical data on it. It's just that it might be longer to reinstall everything than to clone, and my centralized cloning setup is just not ready yet.

Comment: And concerning the end-to-end error, the counters seem persistent, so I'm really puzzled about how one or two single error over 5K running hours could be considered a pre-fail situation. But that's another subject.

Comment: First attempt at cloning one of the RAID-0 drives to the new disk with dd failed. I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preference would be to use something like acronis to image your setup onto a spare (or usb) drive, then wipe the RAID config, create a new one and initialise through controller, then reimage back to the RAID.

Comment: RAID 0 = striped... not mirror. If a drive "might fail", the contents can still be copied off, which is what rebuilding does. Because it's not mirrored, there is only one copy of the data. If a drive is unavailable, the contents cannot be copied off, so a rebuild with one or more drives missing or unreadable in RAID 0 is not possible.

Comment: Well noted - now I'm baffled wondering how it rebuilt previously?!?! Scrub my 1st option and do the second.

Comment: His original drive had not failed yet, it was just a S.M.A.R.T. report indicating imminent failure. I presume the controller software provides an easy rebuild option when this is detected, but the same option could not be found when all drives are reported as healthy.

Comment: @Bob Yes, the rebuild is triggered by flagging the disk as spared in the Intel RST console, and there's no option to cancel it once it started.

Comment: This is the solution I used in the end. After cloning I met many issues with the BCD information, which I only got straight once I got a full-night sleep :]